# Pandas returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, read-sql

I'm using pd.read_sql and sqlserver to get the column names from a specific table. Pandas however only returns a empty dataframe whereas I'm getting valid results from ssms. Here is the code I'm using:

```
query = f'''select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'Table_name'
'''

df_output = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
```

The result is as follows:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_DEFAULT, IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX, NUMERIC_SCALE, DATETIME_PRECISION, CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG, CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA, CHARACTER_SET_NAME, COLLATION_CATALOG, COLLATION_SCHEMA, COLLATION_NAME, DOMAIN_CATALOG, DOMAIN_SCHEMA, DOMAIN_NAME]
Index: []
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is is still empty if you lose the where clause?

Comment: No. I get a [44 rows x 23 columns] dataframe

Comment: The most obvious explanation seems your `table_name` being wrong. Are you sure there's no typo there or anything?

Comment: In ssms its working. I really do not know why it's not working there. I switched to sqlalchemy rather than using pyodbc+pandas. It's working now.